# ElasticSearch single rollover index configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, python-3.6

I would like to set a *single* json config file that I can load and use via the [python api](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html) to [create indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html) like this:

```
import elasticsearch
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': port}])
es.indices.create(index="my_special_index", body=es_config)
```

The index must be a [time based rollover index](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-time-based-indices-efficiently) over a monthly basis.

This is for creating a static index:

```
es_config = {
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 3,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "stop", "asciifolding"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "alert": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {"type": "long"},
        "title": {"type": "text"},
        "user": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "id": {"type": "long"},
            "name": {"type": "text"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't figured out how to do set up the rollover cluster yet, but is it even possible to do everything in a single config + call?

Comment: Use index template + aliasing with a separate delete/shrink call on the old index at a low usage time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What confused me was that I thought the rollover was a passive process.  But when calling `elasticsearch.indices.rollover()`, it does an active check on the alias/active index to see if the rollover conditions are met, and if yes, then it increments the active index.  Doing an active rollover looks like this:

Given the index config from the question as `index_config`

```
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': port}])

index_name = "test-index-00001"  # initial index name ends with number
alias_name = "test-index"  # we will refer to the alias name from now on
doctype = "test"

# first create index and alias
es.indices.create(index=index_name, body=index_config)

# create alias
es.indices.put_alias(index=index_name, name=alias_name)

for i in range(5):
    import datetime
    doc_body = {"id": i, "title": str(datetime.datetime.now())}
    es.index(index=alias_name, doc_type=doctype, body=doc_body)
    time.sleep(0.1)

time.sleep(1)  # es needs about a second
rollover_config = {"conditions": {"max_age": "10d", "max_docs": 3}}
rollover_ret = es.indices.rollover(alias=alias_name, body=rollover_config)
print(rollover_ret)

for i in range(5):
    import datetime
    doc_body = {"id": i, "title": str(datetime.datetime.now())}
    es.index(index=alias_name, doc_type=doctype, body=doc_body)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

When you check your index you'll find `test-index-00001` contains *five* and not 3 items (like the rollover_config declares) because the rollover only happens after those 5 have already been indexed.

---

In order to get a passive rollover, we can make use of ElasticSearch's automatic index creation coupled with the template system.  Say we want to create a new index for every calendar month (and second for copy paste testing):

First, create the [template config](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html) with the alias and template fields:

```
{
  "aliases": {"alerts-index": {}},
  "template": "alerts-index-*",
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 3,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
  "mappings": {
    "alert": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {"type": "long"},
        "title": {"type": "text"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then create the template with an inital index name that follows the YYYYMM suffix:

```
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': port}])

alias_name = "test-index"
doctype = "test"
initial_index_name = "{}-{}".format(alias_name, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%S"))

es.indices.create(index=initial_index_name, body=index_config)
time.sleep(1)

for i in range(5):
    doc_body = {"id": i, "title": str(datetime.datetime.now())}
    indexname = "{}-{}".format(aliasname, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%S"))
    rets = es.index(index=alias_name, doc_type=doctype, body=doc_body)
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

And here you should see your documents ending up in multiple indices based on time.